# Symfony Encrypt Password

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

i'm using symfony 3 with FormBuilder.

now i create Register Form..

one problem that i get it's to use encode to encrypt the Password

today i'm using Like this:

```
public function SignupAction(Request $request){
    $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($form->getData());
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Site:Register.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

every filed is entered to DB.
but the password is not encrypted.

how can i encrypt the password?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the docs: [How to implement a registration form.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html)

Basically, your `RegisterType` should have a default class the `User` which implements `UserInterface` and the password should be encrypted when you save the form.

Answer (score 0):

In symfony 2.7 there is a class named MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.

So you can get an encoder:

```
 $encoder = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder($algorithm,$encode_as_base64, $iterations);
```

You can fill the value of $algorithm, $encode_as_base64 and $iterations whith the configuration of your security.yml parsing the content of security.yml with Yaml::parse. Or simply using the same values defined there.

Once you have the enconder, call the method encodePassword

```
 $password = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $salt)
```

that return the encoded password with the same config of your encoder. Note that you must supply a $salt value. You can make use of [random_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) as is suggested.